# How can I apply syntax highlighting to an ActiveAdmin row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, syntax-highlighting, arbre

I'm storing Ruby code in a database so that if an administrator needs to tweak the code logic, they use ActiveAdmin to make edits. My app is written in such a way to load & call this code from the database.

My problem now is that the text rendered in the ActiveAdmin UI show page is not very readable code because it is not monospaced or syntax highlighted. How can I apply syntax highlighting to this particular row?

Would you use the Rouge gem? If so, can you wrap your code or do you need to monkey-patch ActiveAdmin? What other solutions exist?

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  show do |model|
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :logic # render this logic text as Ruby code
      row :created_at
      row :updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Arbe](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre) syntax to wrap it in a `pre` or `code` tag:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  show do |model|
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :logic, do |logic|
        pre( code(model.logic, class: 'lang-ruby') )
      end
      row :created_at
      row :updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

You could also use the `code` tag instead of `pre`, they're just slightly different. Either way any more serious customization should be done with CSS.

Original Poster's Note: wrap the `code` block with `pre` if using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It got me started in the right direction. I will edit it for further clarity. I wish the docs for Arbre and ActiveAdmin had more examples. I ended up source diving and inferred how to wrap the `code` and `pre` tags from this spec: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/9d91d156d17a905e50b82f2b85ec483598489307/spec/unit/views/components/attributes_table_spec.rb#L127

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.